# twitter4j login android

Tags: android, twitter, authentication, twitter4j

I followed the tutorial at http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/ the only things I changed was the `TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY`, `TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET` and put the `loginToTwitter()` function into a AsyncTask because it was moaning that network communication should not be done on the main activity. I also made sure that on my application twitter settings that the Callback URL was filled in a so it acted like a browser application.

I get to the bit where I login into twitter then get returned back to the application

the bit that doesn't enter code here work for me is:

```
> AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken,
> verifier);
```

which returns a null value

I checked the variable "verifier" which is not null and then "requestToken" which has three values.

```
token={has value}
tokenSecret={has value}
secretKeySpec={null}
```

Does it matter if "secrectKeySpec" is null, or is this a red herring

Can someone please tell me what is going wrong.

Comment: @ Jack Bilbo, did you get solution for this problem. I'm also stuck with this issue for almost two days and could get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, however after dumping the StackTrace I discovered that:

```
AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
```

needs to be put on its own thread. Method getOAuthAccessToken is executing an HttpConnection on the main UI thread hence producing:

```
System.err android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you guide me how to rectify this issue

Comment: @Manikandan - you need to execute this code using androids AsyncTask class. Inside the doInBackground method insert: AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html